# Re:Javascript closure. How the variable inside of the mother object become the same as the mother object?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have a question about public variable and closure. 
  In the following code, how come the 'temp' variable inside of the mother 
  object can be used like the mother object?

For example, in the following code, if you type

```
console.log(pizzaA.getToppings());
```

You can get "3"

A bit confusing because if you return the "temp", it is still a property of 
  mother object. So that means, I think I have to type as follows
  "console.log(pizzaA.temp.getToppings());"

Isn't it?

```
var Pizza = function () {
    var crust = 'thin'; 
    var toppings = 3; 
    var getToppings = function () { return toppings; }; ​ 
    var temp = {};
    temp.getToppings = getToppings;
    ​return temp;
};

var pizzaA = new Pizza(); 
console.log(pizzaA.getToppings());
```

Comment: `Pizza` is not a constructor, because you return an object from it. There is no such thing as a “public variable” in JavaScript. `temp` is a variable, not a property of anything.

Comment: The non-Java-antipattern way to write this is https://jsfiddle.net/L2g2hzkt/.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is *not* a property of the instantiated object - it is the instantiated object itself. When a constructor returns an object, that object is exactly what the result of calling the constructor is assigned to. That is, when you do

```
var pizzaA = new Pizza();
```

and Pizza has

```
return temp;
```

then the `temp` object gets assigned to `pizzaA`. Since the `temp` object has a property `getToppings`, you can call `getToppings` directly on `temp`, and you can also call it directly on `pizzaA`, because they both reference the same object in memory.

Comment: Thank you everyone! So, when there is a return, the result of return will be assigned to the instance of the object, in this case "pizzaA" 

Thank you!

Comment: When you call a function with `new`, if that function returns something explicitly, it'll be assigned to the result *only if the return value is an object.* If the return value is not an object, it'll be ignored. For example https://jsfiddle.net/46708zt4/ But, as others said, a function being called with `new` *shouldn't* ever explicitly return something.

Answer (score 0):

Key points:

1. Javascript function behaves itself as a Class
2. `this` keyword in the function behaves as instance of the Class

You can do either

```
var Pizza = function () {
    this.crust = 'thin'; 
    this.toppings = 3; 
    this.getToppings = function () {
      return this.toppings;
    };
};

var pizza = new Pizza();
console.log(pizza.getToppings()); //prints 3
```

OR (more of a generic way)

```
var Pizza = function (options) {
    var crust = options.crust; 
    var toppings = options.toppings; 
    this.getToppings = function () {
        return toppings;
    };
    this.getCrust = function () {
        return crust;
    };
};

var pizza = new Pizza({ crust: 'thin', toppings: 3 });
console.log(pizza.getToppings()); //prints 3
console.log(pizza.getCrust()); //prints thin
```